# Javascript - Lógica Manipular dados de Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com uma problema de lógica muito complexo. Tenho que comparar 4 arrays e fazer com que eles trabalhem juntos. Vou explicar melhor

Exemplo de como pode vir:

```
var mesA = [ "fev", "mar", "jun" ]
var valorA = [ 50,   50,    50 ]

var mesB = [ "jan", "fev", "mar", "jul", "ago" ]
var valorB = [ 25,    25,   25,    25,    25 ]

var mesA_Final = []
var valorA_Final = []

var mesB_Final = []
var valorB_Final = []
```

Como deve ficar o output disso:

```
var mesA_Final = [ "jan", "fev", "mar", "jun", "jul", "ago"  ]
var valorA_Final = [ 0,     50,    50,   50,     0,     0    ]

var mesB_Final = [ "jan", "fev", "mar", "jun", "jul", "ago"  ]
var valorB_Final = [ 25,   25,    25,     0      25    25    ]
```

Eu preciso fazer uma comparação desses 2 arrays, ordenar eles pela nome do mês, e comparar ambos arrays para que tirem suas diferenças e insiram valor `0` no mês que um tem e o outro não tenha, e vice versa.

> **Obs¹:** esses 4 arrays sempre virão com mês e valor corretos, se por exemplo vierem 3 meses, virão 3 valores. 
>   
> **Obs²:** O que virá na dupla de arrays é dinâmico, podem vir 1 mês 1 valor, como pode vir 2 meses 2 valores, 3 meses 3 valores (...)

O máximo que cheguei foi nisso: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyyjd3L8/2/)

Alguem tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Você tem valores que são ligados e arrays diferentes, por que não fazer um array de objetos que tem `mes` e `valor`? Ficaria muito mais facil de ordenar. Por exemplo: 

`mesA = [{mes: 'jan', valor: 50}, {mes: 'fev', valor: 50}, {mes: 'mar', valor: 50}];`

Comment: Porque do jeito que esta agora, pra ordenar da forma que você deseja ficara muito trabalhoso e difícil de entender.

Comment: Acho que fiz algum progresso com o seu código, dá uma olhada: https://jsfiddle.net/ukz5uves/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto deve fazer o que você deseja (comentado):

```
var mesA = [ "fev", "mar", "jun" ]
var valorA = [ 50,   50,    50 ]

var mesB = [ "jan", "fev", "mar", "jul", "ago" ]
var valorB = [ 25,    25,   25,    25,    25 ]

var mesA_Final = []
var valorA_Final = []

var mesB_Final = []
var valorB_Final = []

// criei uma array com a ordem dos meses. necessário para organizar as arrays mesA_Final e mesB_Final
var meses = ['jan','fev','mar', 'abr','mai','jun','jul','ago','set','out','nov','dez'];

function rodar(){
    // verificar se valores em mesB tem em mesA
    $.each(mesB,function(e,v){
        mesA_Final.push(v);
    });

    // inserir valores de mesA em mesA_final
    $.each(mesA,function(e,v){
        if(mesA_Final.indexOf(v) == -1){
            mesA_Final.push(v);
        }
    });

    // organizar valores na ordem do mês
    mesA_Final.sort(function(a,b){
        return meses.indexOf(a) > meses.indexOf(b);
    });

    // inserir valores em valorA_Final
    $.each(mesA_Final,function(e,v){
        if(mesA.indexOf(v) == -1){
            valorA_Final.push(0);
        }else{
            valorA_Final.push(valorA[mesA.indexOf(v)]);
        }
    });

    // B

    // verificar se valores em mesA tem em mesB
    $.each(mesA,function(e,v){
        mesB_Final.push(v);
    });

    // inserir valores de mesB em mesB_final
    $.each(mesB,function(e,v){
        if(mesB_Final.indexOf(v) == -1){
            mesB_Final.push(v);
        }
    });

    // organizar valores na ordem do mês
    mesB_Final.sort(function(a,b){
        return meses.indexOf(a) > meses.indexOf(b);
    });

    // inserir valores em valorB_Final
    $.each(mesB_Final,function(e,v){
        if(mesB.indexOf(v) == -1){
            valorB_Final.push(0);
        }else{
            valorB_Final.push(valorB[mesB.indexOf(v)]);
        }
    });
}
```

```js
var mesA = [ "fev", "mar", "jun" ]
var valorA = [ 50,   50,    50 ]

var mesB = [ "jan", "fev", "mar", "jul", "ago" ]
var valorB = [ 25,    25,   25,    25,    25 ]

var mesA_Final = []
var valorA_Final = []

var mesB_Final = []
var valorB_Final = []

// criei uma array com a ordem dos meses. necessário para organizar as arrays mesA_Final e mesB_Final
var meses = ['jan','fev','mar', 'abr','mai','jun','jul','ago','set','out','nov','dez'];

function rodar(){
 // verificar se valores em mesB tem em mesA
 $.each(mesB,function(e,v){
  mesA_Final.push(v);
 });

 // inserir valores de mesA em mesA_final
 $.each(mesA,function(e,v){
  if(mesA_Final.indexOf(v) == -1){
   mesA_Final.push(v);
  }
 });
 
 // organizar valores na ordem do mês
 mesA_Final.sort(function(a,b){
  return meses.indexOf(a) > meses.indexOf(b);
 });

 // inserir valores em valorA_Final
 $.each(mesA_Final,function(e,v){
  if(mesA.indexOf(v) == -1){
   valorA_Final.push(0);
  }else{
   valorA_Final.push(valorA[mesA.indexOf(v)]);
  }
 });

 // B

 // verificar se valores em mesA tem em mesB
 $.each(mesA,function(e,v){
  mesB_Final.push(v);
 });

 // inserir valores de mesB em mesB_final
 $.each(mesB,function(e,v){
  if(mesB_Final.indexOf(v) == -1){
   mesB_Final.push(v);
  }
 });
 
 // organizar valores na ordem do mês
 mesB_Final.sort(function(a,b){
  return meses.indexOf(a) > meses.indexOf(b);
 });

 // inserir valores em valorB_Final
 $.each(mesB_Final,function(e,v){
  if(mesB.indexOf(v) == -1){
   valorB_Final.push(0);
  }else{
   valorB_Final.push(valorB[mesB.indexOf(v)]);
  }
 });
 
 // daqui pra baixo é apenas para apresentação, pode apagar essas linhas
 $.each(mesA_Final,function(e,v){
  $("#teste").append(v+", ");
 });
 
 $("#teste").append("<br>");

 $.each(valorA_Final,function(e,v){
  $("#teste").append(v+", ");
 });

 $("#teste").append("<br><br>");

 $.each(mesB_Final,function(e,v){
  $("#teste").append(v+", ");
 });
 
 $("#teste").append("<br>");

 $.each(valorB_Final,function(e,v){
  $("#teste").append(v+", ");
 });
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Checar" onclick="rodar()" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="teste"></div>
```

Comment: Boa lógica! Obrigado :)